# VBA Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remind my self for due dates by using below code.After i run it sends me emails for all cases when date is achieved but when i put another due date it did not work if i do not run again.Please i need some help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub email()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set r = Range("A361:A370")

    For Each cell In r

        If Date - cell.Value = 30 Then

            Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
            Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
            Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant

            Email_Subject = "Reminder"
            Email_Send_From = "rdube02@gmail.com"
            Email_Send_To = "rdube02@gmail.com"
            Email_Cc = ""
            Email_Bcc = ""
            Email_Body = "Please remind  "

            On Error GoTo debugs
            Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
            With Mail_Single
            .Subject = Email_Subject
            .To = Email_Send_To
            .cc = Email_Cc
            .BCC = Email_Bcc
            .Body = Email_Body
            .send
            End With

        End If

    Next


    Exit Sub

debugs:
        If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: When you run it the first time I am assuming you cause to procedure to run by some action you take. If you want to run when you change the value in a cell then you need to use that change to "trigger" the procedure to run. Research "Change Events" for worksheets.

Comment: When i do first run it sends reminder for all cases where condition is met.After i put new value with exact date that i got emails before and for this it did not send the email if do not run again . I would like to make this update automatically because otherwise would not be worth.

Comment: You need to research events as I said previously. Specifically those associated with worksheet, Those fire when something "happens". I'll get you started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change ... When it is suggested you do some research, you should kindly do that. Regards